Why does mocking dynamic import return a proxy object
I have the following (simplified) code under test:
export const loadCommand = async (fqdnPath) => {
    return import(fqdnPath);
};

and a test of that dynamic import method:
import { test, expect, vi } from 'vitest';

import { loadCommand } from 'code-under-test';

const mockModule = { run: vi.fn().mockReturnValue('test') };
const commandsRootPath = '/path/to/modules';

vi.mock('/path/to/modules', () => mockModule);

test('should return module', async () => {
    // result is a proxy object of mockModule 
    const result = await loadCommand(commandsRootPath);

    // Have to un-proxy it to compare the objects
    const unproxied = { ...result };

    expect(unproxied).toEqual(mockModule);
});

This test passes.  But why is the module returned by my dynamic import wrapped in a proxy object when this doesn't happen when running the code outside of tests?  Can I mock the dynamic import in a way to avoid the proxy?  And is there a way to expect of the proxy without 'unproxying' it?
